# hibernate 5.2.12: can session.saveOrUpdate but not session.createQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

Caused by:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/Query;

data persists, but I cannot select it.

Same thing happens when I `session.getNamedQuery`

Comment: You compile your code with a hibernate version, but run it with a different one. That's why the JVM tells you that this method doesn't exist: it existed at compilation time, but doesn't exist ay runtime.

Comment: wildfly 11 is using 5.2.12

Answer (score 0):

adding 
  `<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2"/>`
to persistence.xml fixed it